# Post request doesn't work as long with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, httpurlconnection, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am using Selenium to browse a site in Java. In my code Firefox is launched.

Once I access to a site through Firefox, I create a url connection to make a post request for another server.

The problem is that the post request doesn't work if I try immediately to send it. But if I make a delay through `Thread.sleep(20000)` before calling the request, it works. Why?

Comment: Show your code. Your question is too general at the moment.

Comment: Your post request also rely on Session, once the page is fully loaded and you cookies are stored - you should be fine to fire the POST. Just monitor the page ready state.

Answer (score 0):

I find out there is a problem with the site I attempted to connect ...